# Does "What Have You Say" Mean the same as "What Have You"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I have been listening to the commentaries to "Lord of the Rings, The Two Towers". I've just heard [Grant Major](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0538194/) say,

> The horses were acquired, other than our own stable of horses, en
>   masse, from the farms that were around the place, pony clubs and *what
>   have you say*.

This appears to be used in the same way that I might use "and what have you".

Is this the same meaning?

I believe Mr. Major is from New Zealand, as this was a New Zealand production.

Comment: It's a bungled conflation of two different idiomatic usages - *"and what have you"* in this context means *"and similar things"*. But *"say"* here means *"for example"*, which logically makes no sense, since **all possible** alternatives are implied by *"and what have you"*.

Answer (score 4):

It seems this was most likely a verbal stumble rather than an actual Kiwi-specific idiom. The only reference I can find to "what have you say" is as an interrogative meaning "What have you to say [in regards to a topic]?" which obviously wouldn't apply here. Given the context (that is, a partial list of items) it seems reasonable to conclude that (if indeed the variant was intentional at all) this particular phrase does have an identical meaning.

Comment: Newfie is slang for someone from New Zealand? I always thought it referred to someone from Newfoundland.

Comment: Agh, you're right. I somehow mixed up Newfie and Kiwi.  I'll go edit that out.

Comment: ..though I have heard *Newzie* in this context. (I believe it's an Aussie term.)